# Access keys of pandas dataframe when using groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter, ipython, groupby

I have the following database:

[image]

And I would like to know how many times a combination of BirthDate and Zipcode is repeated throughout the data table:

[image]

Now, my question is: How can I access the keys of this output? For instance, how can I get Birthdate=2000101 ZipCode=8002, for i = 0?

The problem is that this is a 'Series' object, so I'm not able to use .columns or .loc here.

Comment: BTW the first image looks like confidential data, maybe you should delete it

Comment: @DavidMasip No, no. It's fake! Gràcies!

Comment: ok my bad, did I answer your question?

Comment: @DavidMasip you did! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```py
df.groupby(['BirthDate', 'ZipCode']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'n'})
```

and now you have a data frame that you can easily manipulate.